# Change the edit page for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I've been looking for this all day and can't find it.

I'm working on a custom contacts page and I am using the custom post type feature so that I can have more control over it. I'm looking to change the edit page to be a custom template, (example when I go to `/wp-admin/post.php?post=1234&action=edit`), I want it to show a custom page. I don't need any meta boxes or anything. Perhaps the editor, but near the bottom of the page (not at the default top).

I've found how to remove the meta boxes, but I haven't found how to get a clean slate on the CPT edit page.

```
function remove_metaboxes(){
    remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', 'obpcontacts', 'normal'); // Excerpt box
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'obpcontacts', 'normal'); // Comment status box
    remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'obpcontacts', 'normal'); // Comment box
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_metaboxes',11 );
```

Thoughts on how to create a custom template in the wp-admin edit section for my custom post type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create my own edit.php admin page code or template for my custom post type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108891/how-to-create-my-own-edit-php-admin-page-code-or-template-for-my-custom-post-typ)

Comment: Don't think so. Read that one hours ago, and it didn't quite explain how to define my own div's to display my custom fields for the edit page. Also, when I set `show_ui` to false, I lose the whole CPT in my admin menu - also not ideal. Unless I'm just not connecting the dots?

Comment: Yes, if you set the CPT to `false` you do lose all of the default menus and interfaces. You want a clean slate. That is as clean as it gets. You can then build your own user interface for the CPT.

Comment: What you are doing above, by the way, is the way to go about removing the parts of the default edit screen that are removable-- not all parts are. That is the problem you are having. Only parts of the edit screen are alterable. You will never get a clean slate. Building from scratch is the only way to remove everything.

Comment: Yes, exactly what my question is. How do I get to a clean slate? The proposed duplicate you've voted for doesn't help me out too much. Like I said - I'm not connecting the dots on this one.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know you can remove almost everything except the title `h2` tag,  and the `.postbox-container` border. Also note that the `#message` is not visible by default but can pop up depending on what you do.

When you register your CPT set `supports` to an empty array.

```
'supports' => array ('')
```

Then you can use the following to unset the publish and slug (the slug in not visible by default but it is there under screen options),

```
function remove_metaboxes(){
    remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'obpcontacts', 'normal'); // Slug
    remove_meta_box('submitdiv', 'obpcontacts', 'side'); // Publish box
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_metaboxes', 11 );
```

You will be left with a few elements that might need to be removed with javascript:

```
//jQuery enqueue only on your CPT
.removeClass("wrap");  //remove all CSS
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the functionality (as opposed to hiding the functionality) you can remove it entirely in the list of arguments supplied to `register_post_type()`.

This will only display the title and editor fields.

```
$args = array(
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' )
);
```

**Possible supports:**

- 'title'
- 'editor' (content)
- 'author'
- 'thumbnail' (featured image, current theme must also support post-thumbnails)
- 'excerpt'
- 'trackbacks'
- 'custom-fields'
- 'comments' (also will see comment count balloon on edit screen)
- 'revisions' (will store revisions)
- 'page-attributes' (menu order, hierarchical must be true to show Parent option)
- 'post-formats' add post formats, see Post Formats